# Unable to Utilize Full Microsoft BI Functionality with Local Data due to Privacy Concerns

Tags: security, privacy, data-protection

Our business analysis department has submitted a ticket expressing their inability to utilize the full power of Microsoft BI while their data is stored locally on our network. Due to strict data security and compliance requirements, our data is currently stored on-premises.
Inorder to use full power of Microsoft BI, data has to be shifted to cloud.

Desired outcome:

Enable full Microsoft BI functionality for our business analysts while maintaining data security and compliance. Address concerns regarding:

- Can Microsoft BI integrate with state-of-the-art privacy-enhancing technologies like Differential Privacy (DP) and Homomorphic encryption to ensure data privacy when performing analysis on local data?
- Local implementation: Does Microsoft offer documentation or resources
  related to implementing Microsoft BI locally with specific focus on
  utilizing advanced features and functionalities with local data
  access? Our previous attempts to find such information in Microsoft's
  documentation have been unsuccessful.

Questions:

- What are the best practices for enabling full Microsoft BI
  functionality with local data storage while adhering to security and
  compliance regulations?
- Does Microsoft BI offer any built-in support such as API for DP and Homomorphic encryption or recommend specific libraries or tools for integration?
- Where can we find detailed documentation on implementing and
  utilizing advanced Microsoft BI features with local data access?